# Xamarin Forms Font Icons displaying wrong symbols

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

In development I have no issues with FontAwesome icons used within my app, however, as soon as other devices install it in testing/production the icons appear incorrectly. I will show screenshots below.

I really appreciate anyone giving some input to this, it's quite problematic to the point where I am considering going back to images.

It seems they map incorrectly on new device installations. Sometimes I get weird Chinese characters instead. The below is just one example, this behaviour happens across the board.

##### Font Class

```
[assembly: ExportFont("fontello.ttf", Alias = "Fontello")]
namespace TestApp.Fonts
{
    // cut class short for readability but it has a lot more icon codes
    static class FontelloFont
    {
        public const string MapMarkerO = "\ue82c"; // This is the icon used in the photo of how it should look like
        public const string OccupierO = "\ue832"; // This is the icon that appears in place of whats above when it shouldn't
```

##### Usage

```
<Label Text="{x:Static fonts:FontelloFont.MapMarkerO}" 
       FontSize="35"
       FontFamily="Fontello"/>
```

##### What should appear

[image]

##### What actually appears

[image]

Comment: Can you add code to log the string at the time it is displayed?  To see whether it has somehow changed. Also, if you are using any type of code obfuscator, make a build without it. To see if that is the cause.